# formating e notation and division in python

Tags: python, floating-point, format, precision, division

I have

```
"%f"%(9584629447823472134871239847192/2)
```

when I run this in idle the output I get is

```
4792314723911735847389621125120.000000
```

As we all know that the output is not correct. I am new in this. Kindly help how to get the correct output.

The output should be this

```
4792314723911736067435619923596
```

Comment: Kindly see the last `2` present in the input of a large number. The last digit of output can only be 6 or 1 but we get `0`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using floating point arithmetic, which [isn’t precise](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Use integer arithmetic if appropriate in your situation and you want precise results. Integer division in Python is done [using the `//` operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

For example,

```
"%d"%(9584629447823472134871239847192//2)
```